# Python: list of dictionaries, how to get values of a specific key for multiple items of the list?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
dict_list = [{'key1': 'dict1_value1', 'key2': 'dict1_value2', 'key3': 'dict1_value3'},
{'key1': 'dict2_value1', 'key2': 'dict2_value2', 'key3': 'dict2_value3'},
{'key1': 'dict3_value1', 'key2': 'dict3_value2', 'key3': 'dict3_value3'},
{'key1': 'dict4_value1', 'key2': 'dict4_value2', 'key3': 'dict4_value3'},
{'key1': 'dict5_value1', 'key2': 'dict5_value2', 'key3': 'dict5_value3'}]
```

getting the value for 'key3' for the second list item is like:

```
dict_list[1]['key3']
dict2_value3
```

and also the code below returns items 2:4 from the list:

```
dict_list[1:3]
```

What if I want to get values for 'key3' for multiple items from the list. like

```
dict_list[1:3]['key3']
```

something similar to what we do in MATLAB.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> [x.get('key3') for x in dict_list[1:3]]
['dict2_value3', 'dict3_value3']
```

Comment: Why `get`? In the OP's example the key is always present, which means that you can safely use `x['key3']`. Also, using `get` would insert unwanted `None`s inside the list, so it doesn't solve anything. If the presence of the key is not guaranteed then either `[x['key3'] for x in dict_list[1:3] if 'key3' in x]` or `[el for el in (x.get('key3') for x in dict_list[1:3]) if el is not None]` would solve the issue.

Comment: @Bakuriu Agree with you, but it will not insert unwanted none, because the presence of the key is true,

Answer (score 3):

```
[dict_list[i]['key3'] for i in xrange(1,3)]
```

OR

```
[operator.itemgetter('key3')(dict_list[i]) for i in range(1,3)]
```

OR

```
map(operator.itemgetter('key3'), itertools.islice(dict_list, 1,3))
```

Comment: itemgetter has no business being in that list comprehension :p. The first and 3rd are ok though. Keep in mind that map doesn't return a list anymore in Python3

Answer (score 2):

`[x['key3'] for x in dict_list[1:3]]`