# filter latest text entry from models textfield and parse it into the list django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class TrademarkModel(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created", )
```

I wan't to `filter` latest `description` entry and I want to parse it into the list, so I can run that list against `xml` and do some additional counting.
I'm doing something like this

```
result = TrademarkModel.objects.values()
list_values = [entry for entry in result]
return list_values
```

and for the result I've got this:

```
[{'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 11, 58, 14, 30162, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 6,
  'description': u'c'},
 {'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 11, 57, 22, 674450, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 5,
  'description': u'Test'},
 {'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 11, 55, 14, 376727, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 4,
  'description': u'Test'},
 {'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 11, 32, 31, 4703, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 3,
  'description': u'Non Building materials'},
 {'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 11, 31, 35, 244154, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 2,
  'description': u'Testing'},
 {'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 7, 20, 29, 920155, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  u'id': 1,
  'description': u'Testing'}]
```

This is not ideal, because I need to do additional parsing of `list_values`, so I can get latest entry.

My question is what is the most elegant way of extracting latest entry from `description` and parse it into the list?

Comment: you could probably use the [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function. [python tips](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) has soom good examples of how to use it.

Comment: @JosieThompson nice suggestion, but I'll use it after I extract latest `description` entry.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17586034/4661269) help with what you're asking?

Comment: @JosieThompson it will help me for this second part.

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested that if I want to filter out `description` I need to use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), that was also returning all entries from the database, but this for example

```
TrademarkModel.objects.all().values_list('description', flat=True).latest('created')
```

is returning just the latest entry from the database, so now I can parse it into the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you could also theoretically do something like

`max(TrademarkModel.objects.values(), key=lambda d: d['created'])['description']`

utilizing the `key` keyword argument in the builtin `max` function to sort by date, then grab the `description.` I'm completely unfamiliar with django though so I'm biased in that sense. I have no idea how `values_list().latest()` compares in times. I haven't tested this code though...

Comment: interesting, noted, I'll play with this and compare the two, this example from my answer is pure django, but still I can use this too